# Android UI library that has Action Bars, Dashboards, etc

Tags: android

Is there an Android UI Library that has components like Action Bars and Dashboards? A lot of new applications seem to have these components, so I was hoping there was a solution available (either free or paid).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not that I know of.  Your best bet is to look at an app like [iosched](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/) and see how the components are implemented.  It probably wouldn't be too hard to create an action bar and dashboard as a reusable widget, but as far as I know, no one has done so yet.

Comment: +1 The Google IO schedule app is a great resource for those UI components - I used it for many of my apps.

Answer (score 9):

Also have a look at [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) which allows you to implement e.g. the action bar.

Comment: I cannot recommend GreenDroid highly enough. Very well thought out library.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar/

Take a look at the link above for one of the best action bar libraries I have come across so far. Its quite straight forward to use.

Answer (score 2):

In short: No! There is no such library to create a dashboard or actionbar in a short way.

In this video [Android UI design patterns](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=M1ZBjlCRfz0), however, developers state in Q&A part that they may release a library to achieve those UI design patterns in the future.

Until then you need to design and implement your dashboard and stuff. I strongly recommend to checkout and take a look the code at iosched as Eric already mentioned. There is a beautiful dashboard implemented.

You can also use [DroidDraw](http://www.droiddraw.org/) to design and implement UI views easily by drag&drop. DroidDraw can also then export your design to android xml file.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is.  [DroidUX](http://www.droidux.com) is a UI/UX component library with ActionBars, Dashboard, GalleryFlow, Wheel, ScrollableTab, and other components/widgets that you can easily use to build the UI for your app.

Check it out at [www.droidux.com](http://www.droidux.com).

Comment: It comes with a high price tag for an indie developer to subscribe to, don't you think?

Answer (score 0):

If you want external library You might be interested to have a look at ActionBarSherlock library. But android.support.v7 libraries ActionBarCompact  componnt can also do this job without an external library.